Site dropped from 1st to 30th after moving hosts and changing to PHP
For about the last 18 months my site (jimpix.co.uk) has been first in the US region on Google search results for the phrase "username generator".
It used to run on Classic ASP code on a Windows Server and had done since I started the site in the year 2000.
On 24th May I changed hosts to a Litespeed Server and run the site on PHP now instead.
The the old .asp pages have a 301 redirect on to the .php version of the page.
I've checked on a redirect checking site to see the redirect works okay - e.g. via https://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php
Response:
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Connection: close

However, as a result of the move the site has dropped to about 30th in the US region for "username generator", and from 1st to 2nd for the UK.
The bulk of traffic came from the google results from the US region.
I have checked my site on Screaming Frog for issues, and also have looked for issues on Google Search Console but no issues are returned relating to moving from Windows to Litespeed.
The old asp pages appear in Google Search Console here:
Page indexing > Page with redirect
When I look in the site's cPanel, under Errors there are hundreds of errors such as:
2024-05-30 07:18:16.107025 [INFO] [192064] [T0] [66.249.64.7:56201-1#APVH_site.co.uk:443] File not found [/home/site/public_html/this.asp]
I thought that doing the 301 redirect would help reduce the SEO impact of the move - but are all the 404 errors from e.g. google indexing the old .asp pages causing the big drop in where my site is listed now?
I added 29 of the old .asp pages to the removal tool here:
https://search.google.com/search-console/removals
Thinking that might help but that caused the site to drop from 4th to 30th so I've canceled all those requests now.
I wondered if I just need to be patient, or if anyone has any advice about how I can try to restore where my site was in the search results, other than going back to the Windows / Classic ASP setup?
Thanks

It seems like you've realized this, but requesting that Google removes your URLs from search probably caused a major SEO hit. Effectively you were instructing Google to remove your site from their search index. Since the bulk of your search ranking hadn't transferred to the new URLs yet (which happens within 6-12 months after leaving the redirects in place), you basically removed the part of your site that ranks on Google!
Keeping 301 redirects in place (and not blocked/removed from Google in any way) is critical to keep ranking during a website transition like this.
Regarding your redirects:

I thought that doing the 301 redirect would help reduce the SEO impact of the move - but are all the 404 errors from e.g. google indexing the old .asp pages causing the big drop in where my site is listed now?

This makes me worry that your 301 redirects are not actually properly set up. When Google re-crawls and indexes the old .asp pages, it shouldn't be finding any 404 errors. Google should be indexing a 301 redirect at every one of those URLs. When Google indexes each old URL (that serves up a redirect), it will transfer ranking juice to each new URL.
I also noticed that you've been using the word "redirect" singular. Just to make sure we're on the same page, I assume you mean that you've added many redirects - one redirect per page (or otherwise you've used some fancy wildcard redirect) to make sure that every ASP URL is properly redirecting to its corresponding new PHP URL. It won't cut it if you're only redirecting the home page, of course!
Regarding ranking, I'm not sure how quickly ranking can bounce back after you manually remove pages from the Google index. My recommendation in this case would be to put the site back the way it was with the .asp pages and wait a few weeks to see if your rank starts coming back.
Then, next migration attempt, make sure that you:

Check for 404 errors before you publish it. Either your old .asp URLs are properly redirecting with 301 redirects, or they are incorrectly returning 404. To keep your ranking, it's important that they all properly 301 redirect to their corresponding PHP URLs and there are no new 404s where there weren't any before. When you say that you're getting 404 errors for paths like /home/site/public_html/this.asp, this makes me think that your old URLs are not properly redirecting. Visit these old URLs in your browser - if your redirects are set up properly then they should redirect you to the new URL, not give you a 404 page.

Do not use the removal tool at all for this project. If you're feeling impatient, use the URL inspection tool on your old URLs (that you've checked are properly 301 redirecting) and click the "request indexing" button. When Google sees the 301 redirect it will know that the old URL is obsolete, and it will see that you're asking it to transfer search ranking from that URL to the new URL that the redirect points to.



Thanks very much indeed for your very helpful reply. Yes I have screwed up with those removal requests! And yes, I have set up multiple redirects and visiting the .asp URL does redirect to the .php URLs rather than return a 404 error. I've requested a re-index so will just have to be patient, which I should have been in the first place. Thanks again
